# Solr: calculate age in number of years from DOB

Tags: solr, date

I am storing DOB in MySQL DB and while indexing data in SOLR I want to calculate age in years and store it another field

Is there a way to do this.

I can calculate the age when the user first registers and enters the DOB but then there is no way for me to know to update the age of a user every year.

Can you suggest me ways to do this if the doing it while indexing is not the right approach

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can get the calculated field returned with the response.
The calculation can be easily done on the client side, consuming the Solr response.

[Function queries](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery) allow you to use the field values with a lot of operations on it.

e.g. [milli second between the current date and dob](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#ms)

```
ms(NOW,dob)
```

But they are we used just in queries and not be effect the response.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned previously you can use function queries to calculate the age. You can also use a field name alias to return a new field in the Solr response, for example:

```
&fl=age:div(ms(NOW,dob_dt),86400000)
```

would return a new field called **age** with the difference between the dob_dt field and the current date. The function query ms(NOW,dob_dt) will return the milliseconds from dob_dt until the current date. The div() function converts this value to days (i.e, 1000*60*60*24).  Extending this to convert to years (1000*60*60*24*365):

```
&fl=age:div(ms(NOW,dob_dt),31536000000)
```